Integrated circuit amplifier with BJTs
In the circuit below, I'm trying to find the voltage gain. It was given that in small signal analysis,  $$ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} =  \frac{\frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}} }{ 1 + \frac {R_{2}}{AR} } $$.

$$ Figure. 1 $$
The resistance R is resistance between the collector of \$ Q_{6} \$ and ground. Equations of this circuit  are:
$$ \frac{v_{i}}{R_{3}} + \frac{v_{o}}{R_{2}} + \frac{v_{i}}{R_{3}} = 0 $$
$$ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} = \frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}}  $$
Assuming there is a feedback network around the Amplifier with gain -A in this circuit and we are supposed to calculate the voltage gain. How to calculate the feedback factor and bring the voltage gain in the form of \$ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} =  \frac{\frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}} }{ 1 + \frac {R_{2}}{AR} } \$ ?
The above circuit is a simplified version of the following circuit which is from a IC power amplifier LM380 from national semiconductor.

$$ Figure. 2 $$
References:
Figure (1) is from Sedra and smith, Microeelecronic circuits, 7ed, page 871, year 2017, oxford university press.
Figure (2) is from Sedra and smith, Microeelecronic circuits, 7ed, page 869, year 2017, oxford university press. .

What is A*R? A is OL gain, but R?

A is gain of the amplifier with (open loop) gain A in Figure 1. R is resistance between collector of $ Q_{6} $ and ground.

The schematic does not contain this $R$, for clarity it would be better to explicitly draw it as parasitic resistor.

The schematic doesn't show the resistor R. I assumed it is the thevenin resistance seen by the collector  $ Q_{6} $ and it is connected to ground.

@AmitM To 1st order the gain is 50 because twice the vi/R3 current has to be pulled through R2 so the gain is -2 R2/R3. When considering 2nd order effects such as the variation in base current at the VAS (Q12) they are introducing an R to convert this 2nd order effect to a voltage. But if going for 2nd order effects, the circled #7 assumption that vi/(R1/2) is zero is false. We are talking about small signal and with the external bypass present (so that its R1/2) there is a small change there that also needs to be included at this level of analysis. The textbook wrongly ignores it.

The book assumes zero current through R1/2 but there might be some current. Perhaps the current is in micro amperes and the author chose to ignore it. Same with virtual ground at node near circle 5 .In Fig.1  If transistor Q4 is on , then the voltage drop across its emitter base junction cant be zero. So, voltage at node near circle 5 should be non zero ( assuming due to DC bias conditions not shown in Fig.1). Then the node at circle 5 is not a virtual ground. Perhaps the author made it a virtual ground to simply equations.

You write that "it was given that" the gain is
$$ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} =  \frac{\frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}} }{ 1 + \frac {R_{2}}{AR} }$$ But that is only true if \$R\$ is present and then the  drawing becomes like this:

Where you give your "equations for this circuit" you must now change the first one to include the current through \$R\$:
$$ 
 \frac{{\large v_{i}}}{R_{3}} + \frac{{\large v_{o}}}{R_{2}}
 - \frac{{\large v_{o}}/(-A)}{R} +
 \frac{{\large v_{i}}}{R_{3}} = 0, \tag{1}
$$
where the added term is just the voltage over \$R\$ divided by \$R\$. And that voltage was already given as \$\frac{{\large v_o}}{-A}\$ in the drawing (although it claimed \$\frac{{\large v_o}}{-A} \simeq 0\$, which is of course not what we have if \$R\$ actually does play a role).
It should be clear that Eq. \$(1)\$ straightforfwardly gives the required result for the gain.

How did you get voltage gain without R as $ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} = \frac {-R_{2}}{R_{3}}  $. The equations above show that it is $ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} = \frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}}  $.  Can you please show any detailed steps or explanation? Thanks.

Your first equation$$ \frac{v_{i}}{R_{3}} + \frac{v_{o}}{R_{2}} + \frac{v_{i}}{R_{3}} = 0 $$is wrong. For no reason you duplicated the $\frac{v_{i}}{R_{3}}$ term! That gives a false factor $2$. Also note that the circuit of your Fog. 2 is essentially different because it has "+In" and "-In". In your Fig. 1 one of those is $0$. That could also give a factor $2$ difference.

It seems that near the node at circle 14 in Fig..1, the current Vi/R3 is coming from the current mirror on left and it is towards the node along with the current  Vo/R2 + Vi/R3 , both on the top branches in Fig. 1 . The + and - supplies are changed in the differential amplifier. This seems like a approximation because the input at + terminal should be Vi  if it was +Vi/2 earlier and with -Vi/2 at - terminal.  This is my guess.  How did the resistor R become AR? This AR resistor is parallel to R2 because of a virtual ground at node near circle 5 in Fig.1.

You are correct if you are looking at node (14), but then you need to add the current through R
(although you didn't draw it, it is there!). I was looking at (5), but that does not lead to a quicker solution, I see now... I changed the answer to address this.

Equation (2) is not valid anymore. You might want to delete it. With equation, (1), the voltage gain becomes  $ \frac{v_{o}}{v_{i}} =  \frac{\frac {-2R_{2}}{R_{3}} }{ 1 + \frac {R_{2}}{AR} } $.

The problem was vague as it didn't show how R was connected to collector of $ Q_{6} $ and where R was only the output resistance of $ Q_{6} $  or if it included the resistances of $ Q_{4} $, $ Q_{2} $, R5, R2 and R3.. Thanks for your solution.

Yes, it led to a sloppy, "iterative" solution (my fault...) But actually the problem isn't that vague (compared to some other questions we encounter,) it is just formulated in a tricky way. The $R$ is clearly described, not showing it in the schematic is just deliberately making it difficult to see what happens. And the ${\large \frac{v_o}{-A}}\simeq0$ written in the drawing also is strictly speaking not wrong, you just shouldn't read it as ${\large \frac{v_o}{-A}}=0$.

Doing two or three iterations to discover the correct technique is acceptable.

In practical engineering it can even be quite useful to try a few things that are in fact veering off, but it would not be the right strategy for acing an exam!
